# i18n (internationalization) in symfony

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony-1.4

I am using the `__('text')` construct in symfony so I can then internationalise. However I have tried to use it in a setFlash message  as follows

```
$this->getUser()->setFlash('error', __('message'));
```

in the actions/actions.class.php but it give me an error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function __()
```

So am I to assume that I cannot use the `__()` at the action level but only the template level?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In an action you have to use __() using the context:

```
echo $this->getContext()->getI18N()->__('message');
```

You can also use:

```
sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers(array('I18N'));
$this->getUser()->setFlash('error', __('message'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Best option if you are to do this is add this method to your actions.class.php:

```
public function preExecute()
  {
   sfProjectConfiguration::getActive()->loadHelpers(array('I18N'));
   parent::preExecute();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked great for me! Thank you

You can also do $this->loadHelpers(array('I18N')); in your ProjectConfiguration class or frontend|backendConfiguration classes

Regards

Comment: Tried this and it breaks the symfony CLI.